# Expansion of the form by pressing a button

Tags: c#, winforms

Which form element can do the following:
- I press the button, the "additional" part of the form unfolds to the right.

Once I saw something like that, but I do not remember where.

I try to do it with "ToolStripPanel", but it does not work ...
"ToolStripPanel" makes the "red" panel expand to the "blue" territory.
It does not suit me.

What element of the form to use so that the “red” was of a constant size, and the “blue”
 part was unwrapped and rolled up so that the form would increase and decrease?

[image - link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfUXl.gif)

Comment: You can just change the form's size manually. Since you provide no [mcve] of your current setup, it's hard to give a full answer.

Comment: SplitContainer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your image, you could use a [SplitContainer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/splitcontainer-control-windows-forms) but what you see is a 2-step action. First, remove the panel 2, then resize panel 1 to take the newfound space.

Another option is to gradually decrease the size of panel 2, hence giving the illusion of "unfolding"